# Why can't i have classcastexception?

Tags: java

Why can't i have classcastexception? 
E means C in the example, doesn't it?
B is not C, I thought my cast must work only for compiler.
Where is my mistake?

```
public class A{
public static void main(String...s){
    Monitor<C> m = new Monitor<C>(); 
    C arg2 = new C();
    B d = m.f(arg2);
    System.out.println(d);
    }
}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class Monitor<E extends B>{
public E f(E E){
    return (E) new B();//Why this place didn't give me ClassCastException?
}
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your source code, it looks horrible. And please try to make the question clear, it is quite hard to understand.

Comment: Why Monitor alone ? why not M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of type erasure in generics. Since you have generic type `<E extends B>` statement `return (E) new B()` is compiled into `return (B) new B()` so you have not got `ClassCastException`.

Comment: To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods. My bound is (B), isn't it? Maybe then, i'll have (B) new B?

Comment: @user1849430 Yes. You're right.

Answer (score 3):

Read the tutorial about generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Because of type erasure you cannot cast to E, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html